# how to ignore AttributeError: 'NoneType'

Tags: python, attributeerror, nonetype, geopy

```
location = geolocator.geocode(" ".join(address.values()))
if location.longitude is not None:
    node['pos'] = [location.longitude, location.latitude]
```

Don't understand way I'm still getting this error:

```
  File "/home/easypc/Documents/Udacity_nano_degree/Data_Wrangling/audit_vilnius.py", line 167, in shape_element
    if location.longitude is not None:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'longitude'
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: Attribute Error - 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'something'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949252/python-attribute-error-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-something)

Answer (score 9):

It is the `location` variable itself that is `None`, test for that too:

```
if location is not None and location.longitude is not None:
```

or perhaps more simply put:

```
if location:
```